# select nodes in a graph such that any node is close enough to a selected node

Tags: graph-theory

> **Question.**
> Given an undirected graph, select minimum number of nodes, such that any node in the graph can be connected to a selected node with number of edges $\leq k$.

Any faster solution in the special case of $k=1$ and the graph is a tree (i.e. acyclic).

*Example:* $k=1$, graph is a single line of 6 nodes. Solution: O-X-O-O-X-O where X means selected.

Comment: What's the context for this question?

Comment: This is a "resource location problem" and there is a very large literature on different variations that you can find by searching with those keywords.

Comment: This is called "distance domination number" in the graph theory literature.